# Sql: Join separately ordered tables

Tags: sql, join

Let's assume I have two sets of events:

- `Foo`
- `Bar`

where I would always expect `Bar` to follow `Foo`: `Foo -> Bar`. I have a table of `Foo` values:

```
|----|---------------|------|
| id | ordering-foo  | other|
|----|---------------|------|
|1   |1              |X     |
|1   |2              |Y     |
|----|---------------|------|
|2   |1              |X     |
|----|---------------|------|
|3   |2              |X     |
|----|---------------|------|
|4   |1              |X     |
|4   |2              |Y     |
|----|---------------|------|
```

the `ordering` field indicates the order at which the `Foo` events happened per id.

I also have a set of `Bar` events:

```
|----|---------------|-------|
| id | ordering_bar  | other |
|----|---------------|-------|
|1   |A              |XX     |
|1   |B              |YY     |
|----|---------------|-------|
|3   |B              |XX     |
|----|---------------|-------|
|4   |A              |XX     |
|----|---------------|-------|
```

Note that:

- while `Foo` and `Bar` are both ordered, they don't share the same ordering and we can't simply join them on the said ordering values. Here I have simplified them to numbers vs strings. In the problem that inspired this question, these are the timestamps for each Foo/Bar event respectively, which has the property of `foo.ordering < bar.ordering` for a `Foo->Bar` sequence of events, but that's probably not massively helpful to this problem.
- The ordering isn't "???", ie just because we have an order entry of `2`(`B`) doesn't mean we'd necessarily have a `1`(`A`) entry. see entries for id: `3`
- It's possible for us to have a record for `Foo` but not the subsequent `Bar`, ie see entries for id: `2, 4`

I want to end up with:

```
|----|----------|-----------|-----------|
| id | ordering | other-foo | other-bar |
| 1  | 1        | X         | XX        |
| 1  | 2        | Y         | YY        |           
|----|----------|-----------|-----------|
| 2  | 1        | X         | null      |           
|----|----------|-----------|-----------|
| 3  | 2        | X         | XX        |
|----|----------|-----------|-----------|
| 4  | 1        | X         | XX        |
| 4  | 2        | Y         | null      |           
|----|----------|-----------|-----------|
```

How can I get there? In my special case of this problem I only ever have two possible events per event type, per id. ie the ordering values can only ever be: `1,2 / A,B` I played around with things like:

```sql
case
  when count(*) over (partition by foo.id) = 1 and count(*) over (partition by bar.id) = 1 then foo.ordering_foo
  when count(*) over (partition by foo.id) = 2 and count(*) over (partition by bar.id) = 1 then 1
  when count(*) over (partition by foo.id) = 2 and count(*) over (partition by bar.id) = 2 and max(bar.ordering_bar) over (partition by bar.id) = bar.ordering_bar then 2
  when count(*) over (partition by foo.id) = 2 and count(*) over (partition by bar.id) = 2 and min(bar.ordering_bar) over (partition by bar.odering_bar)= bar.ordering_bar then 1
  else -1
end as ordering,
```

ie, I treat each case of:

- 1 foo, 1 bar
- 2 foo, 1 bar
- 2 foo, 2 bar

separately to com up with a composite order. Tho it is likely error-prone, and most importantly I realise this is:

- horrible to read/maintain
- not flexible enough.
- hard to use to get `other` fields.

So I'm curious if you could solve this more elegantly in the generic case.

Comment: How are values from `Foo` matched to values of `Bar`? For instance, how do you know that `(1, 1, X)` should be matched to `(1, A, XX)` and not to `(1, B, YY)`?

Comment: First entry from `Foo` is matched to First entry from `Bar`. Second entry from `Foo` is matched to Second entry from `Bar`. etc.

Comment: First/Second entry per id that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may join the tables using `ROW_NUMBER` as the following:

```
SELECT T.id ,T.ordering_foo, T.other other_foo, D.other other_bar
FROM
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ordering_foo) foo_rn
  FROM foo
) T
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ordering_bar) bar_rn
  FROM bar
) D
ON T.ID=D.ID AND T.foo_rn=D.bar_rn
ORDER BY T.id ,T.ordering_foo
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/VUdFoQO1) on SQL Server.